# Azure table helper check if the item being saved is new or old

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

In my azure app I have a save function for models like this

```
public Organization Save()
{
    TableHelper.Save<Organization>(this);
    // I want to check is this a new entry or an old one being saved?
    return this;
}
```

So I am trying to check if this is an old entry or a new being made. I can have properties on its own but I was hoping azure would have something built in for this thing.

Comment: Are you looking to see if the `Save` operation created a new entity or updated an existing entity?

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to do. I saw a property IsLoaded, does that do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the timestamp property provided by Azure Table Storage. Add a column with **Edm.DateTime** as a datatype. You can put your logic only to update that column as required and the timestamp of the Azure Table will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, maybe we could not find a way to know what operation (insert or update) has been done if there is no logic to implement it currently. But as you mentioned that we can implement it easily by add a property to do that.
You also could send your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to azure storage team, if you would like to.